# Why is caret/cursor invisible in mcedit in Xubuntu 16.04?

Tags: xubuntu, cursor, midnight-commander

I have fresh install of Xubuntu 16.04 and I like to use mcedit in Midnight Commander. However, keyboard cursor (not mouse cursor) is not visible. I can use arrow keys, type and everything works just like cursor would be visible, except it is not.

Is there a way how to make it visible ? I have no idea why it is not visible, because it's just default install of Xubuntu and MC.

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with Xubuntu 16.04.

The solution is to change xfce4-terminal's setting via Edit->Params->Colors->Cursor Color as you needed.

Comment: Had this issue with Guake terminal, changed theme and now works fine. That was pretty annoying.